# Android SDK PATH Error: doesn´t find home directory

Tags: android

I use Ubuntu 12.10 and I tried to follow this guide [Install android sdk and eclipse in Ubuntu 12.04](http://sharepointkunskap.wordpress.com/2012/05/11/install-android-sdk-and-eclipse-in-ubuntu-12-04/#comment-620) but I keep getting this error:

```
 Error: The AVD manager normally uses the user's profile directory to store AVD files. However it failed to find the default profile directory. To fix this, please set the environment variable ANDROID_SDK_HOME to a valid path such as ¨~¨.
```

Any ideas how can I fix this?

Comment: your blog comment says you're running maverick kde, but the question says you're running 12.10.  which is it?

Comment: :). I just installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to export the variable ANDROID_SDK_HOME to the path where your Android SDK is:
example:

```
ANDROID_SDK_HOME=/home/theo/android-sdk/
```

Comment: Well, I suppose it´s like this? ´ 

export ANDROID_SDK_HOME=${PATH}:/home/theo/android-sdk-linux/´   It didn´t work but I assume it´s wrong

Comment: Thanks both. I figure it out :P  I was putting the PATHS on bash_profile instead of bashrc and also putting export and path on the last one. It´ś working thanks Hanynowsky and @Kyle Macey

Answer (score 1):

Do what it says and run

```
ANDROID_SDK_HOME=/home/your_username
```

in the terminal